# blackberry OS 10 development to share screen

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Is it possible to create an application for BBOS10 that shares screen to other phone/PC on wifi network just like Radmin on Windows?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this when the facility is already provided by BBM?

Comment: I want to learn. Not to use the facility. If you don't know how, don't bother replying.

Comment: You have, of course, searched on the BB10 native micro-site here (http://developer.blackberry.com/native/) for assistance before just asking here - no wait, I don't think you have because you haven't mentioned this:  http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__screenshot.html.  If you want people to help you, be polite.  And if you want people to help you, do some research first.

Comment: i already read that. im not that lazy.
it's for screen capturing. I am asking about screen share.

Comment: i can use screen capturing anyway. how to reduce the quality of the jpg file?

Comment: Doni, you just metaphorically flipped off the one person I see around here who is probably best qualified to help you. I would say the answer to your question is yes because there are applications that do that now. The point, however, of stackoverflow is to ask specific questions about code you are trying to write. Usually posting examples of what you have tried is an important aspect of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are talking about sharing the screen regardless of content, rather than sharing the screen for a specific application that you have written.

I am not aware of any "API"s for doing this.

This leaves, I believe two options, which are loosely:

- capture screen shots and forward these
- capture a video of the screen and forward that

Now the screen shot API has been available since fairly early on in BB10 evolution.  To use it you would just create a background Thread and take screen shots at regular intervals, which you would then send, presumably over a socket interface, to the receiving user.  I suspect The biggest issue with this is that it is likely to be extremely data heavy, since the screen shots are complete images, as opposed to a streaming video which is (in my understanding) typically a series of diffs from the preceding frame.

Until very recently, it has not been possible to capture video of the BB screen, but it seems with 10.2, you now can.  Please review this Thread:

[Capture Video](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Display-Capture-API/td-p/1598681)

on the BB10 forum.

Looking at this, it would appear you can capture each video frame and forward that, or presumably, capture the entire stream and forward that.